# PHP+TCPDF foreach fault

Tags: php, foreach, tcpdf

I'm a newer with PHP. My target is transfering inserted data by user in form fields to PDF using TCPDF library. On Windows XP it works fine, everything's functional, but if I try generate PDF on Windows 7, it gives me following report.

```
Notice: Undefined index: startcolumn in C:\xampp\htdocs\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19345
Notice: Undefined index: startx in C:\xampp\htdocs\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19346
Notice: Undefined index: startpage in C:\xampp\htdocs\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19349
Notice: Undefined index: startpage in C:\xampp\htdocs\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19352
Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19352
Notice: Undefined index: startpage in C:\xampp\htdocs\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19353
Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19353
Notice: Undefined index: startpage in C:\xampp\htdocs\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19385
Notice: Undefined index: startx in C:\xampp\htdocs\tcpdf\tcpdf.php on line 19605
TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file
```

Here's the offending code:

```
foreach( $_POST['mat_tit'] as $key => $_POST['mat_tit'] ) {
    $mat_list_data = '
    <table cellpadding="1" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="100%">'.$_POST['mat_tit'].'</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
        <tr>
            <td width="13%">'.$mat_up[$key].'</td>
            <td width="5%">Kč</td>
            <td width="12%">'.$mat_q[$key].'</td>
            <td width="5%">'.$mat_ut[$key].'</td>
            <td width="5%">'.$mat_c[$key].'</td>
            <td width="13%">'.$mat_isum[$key].'</td>
            <td width="5%">Kč</td>
            <td width="6%">'.$mat_vv[$key].'</td>
            <td width="13%">'.$mat_vs[$key].'</td>
            <td width="5%">Kč</td>
            <td width="13%">'.$mat_itot[$key].'</td>
            <th width="5%">Kč</th>
        </tr>
    </table>';
}

// print $mat_list_data
$pdf->writeHTML($mat_list_data, true, true, false, false, '');
```

Is there anybody, who can help me to solve this problem? Thanks a lot guys

Comment: Have u got just one answer or only questions? Maybe this is only about foreach and not about TCPDF but notice the first line of my topic - I'm a newer and this is reason, why I'm asking you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to remove double quotes in your code and use single quotes in your table;

```
$mat_list_data = "
<table cellpadding='1' cellspacing='0'>
....
....        
....
";
```